# Does there exist any sequence of continuous functions that does not converge on the domain but limit of an integral of each function is 0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Is it true or not that

there is a sequence $\{f_n: [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]\}$ of continuous functions such that the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is not convergent for all $x\in [0,1]$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)dx=0$ ?

A function that first come to my mind is $sin(nx)$. It satisfies the limit, but the sequence will converge to $0$ at $x=0$ which is not what we want. Is there any way to make this function discontinuous at $x=0$? Maybe we should disprove this statement instead. I think it's hard to disprove by supposing that there is such sequence but the limit of its integral is not $0$ because we can't use LMCT or LDCT to swap the position of the limit and the integral.

Comment: How about $(\sin{n(x+1)})_n$ ?

Comment: @Mindlack It's not non-negative, is it?

Comment: The example you had in mind can't work, since $\sin(nx)$ is not non-negative. Your question is not completely clear. Do you mean that $f_n(x)$ is divergent for all $x$, or just that it is divergent for some $x$?

Comment: I see. Thanks. Now get to the problem it says $f_n (x)$ is divergent for all $x\in [0,1]$ not just some $x$.

Comment: The answer (or at least one of them) is essentially contained in the famous typewriter sequence.

Comment: @nicomezi: This is basically what my answer is about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true. For each $0\leq m<n$, let $f_{n,m}\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous (which you can choose to be piecewise linear, but you can also choose it to be smooth) function such that $f_{n,m}(x)=1$ for $x\in [\frac{n}{m},\frac{n+1}{m}]$ and $f_{n,m}(x)=0$ for $x\notin (\frac{n-1}{m},\frac{n+2}{m})$.

Then $f_{n,m}$ does not converge anywhere, but the integrals converge to $0$.